# Combine two arrays of different data type

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scores
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("\f");
        int classSize, counterScore, counterName;
        String name;
        double score,average, sum;

        System.out.print("Enter size of class: ");
        classSize = input.nextInt();

        int[] scoreArray = new int[classSize];
        String[] nameArray = new String[classSize];

        counterScore=1;
        counterName = 1;
        average = 0;
        sum = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < classSize; x++)
        {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Student " + counterName++ + " Name: ");
            nameArray[x] = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Student " + counterScore++ + " Score: ");
            scoreArray[x] = input.nextInt();

            sum = sum + scoreArray[x];
            average = sum / classSize;
        }

        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

I have to make an app that allows me to say how many people took a test and then enter their names and scores. I have used two different arrays as one is a string and one a double. My output is meant to read which names got under the average and display the name. I do not know how to combine the two arrays so that it recognizes that this score is related to this name so display that name.

Comment: Create a class `Person` consisting of a name and a score!? And then only create a Person array

Comment: You've pretty much figured it out. You don't need to actually combine the 2 arrays, just realize that the same indices in the 2 arrays correspond to the same person. So nameArray[4] and scoreArray[4] correspond to the same person.

Comment: Or use a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the name and the value the score. But this is less scalable if you later want to add a third information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (add this after your first loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
    {
        if(scoreArray[i] < average) {
            System.out.println(nameArray[i])
        }
    }
```

Or if you want it all on one line:

```
System.out.println("The following students are below average: ")
boolean first = true;
for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
    {
        if(scoreArray[i] < average) {
            if(!first) {
                System.out.println(", ");
                first = false;
            }
            System.out.print(nameArray[i])
        }
    }
```

Also, you should move the line `average = sum / classSize;` outside of your loop, there's no point in re-calculating the average each time.

---

To find out the highest value, keep a temporary variable for the name and another for the highest value, and loop through the students:

```
String highestName = "";
double highestValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
    if(scoreArray[i] > highestValue) {
        highestName = nameArray[i];
        highestValue = scoreArray[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(highestName + " has the highest grade.")
```

Or use this to print more than one student if there's a tie:

```
String[] highestNames = new String[classSize];
int numHighest = 0;
double highestValue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
    if(scoreArray[i] > highestValue) {
        highestNames[0] = nameArray[i];
        numHighest = 1;
        highestValue = scoreArray[i];
    } else if(scoreArray[i] > highestValue) {
        highestNames[numHighest] = nameArray[i];
        numHighest = numHighest + 1;
    }
}

System.out.println("The following student(s) has/have the highest grade: ")
boolean first2 = true;
for (int i = 0; i < numHighest; i++)
    {
        if(!first2) {
            System.out.println(", ");
            first2 = false;
        }
        System.out.print(highestNames[i])
        }
    }
```

---

You can also combine the content of the loop for printing students with grades below average with the one for finding the highest grades to make your program more efficient:

```
String[] highestNames = new String[classSize];
int numHighest = 0;
double highestValue = 0;
System.out.println("The following students are below average: ")
boolean first = true;
for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++)
    {
        if(scoreArray[i] < average) {
            if(!first) {
                System.out.println(", ");
                first = false;
            }
            System.out.print(nameArray[i])
        }
        if(scoreArray[i] > highestValue) {
            highestNames[0] = nameArray[i];
            numHighest = 1;
            highestValue = scoreArray[i];
        } else if(scoreArray[i] > highestValue) {
            highestNames[numHighest] = nameArray[i];
            numHighest = numHighest + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can i ask why you put the boolean in. Sorry im a beginner and still learning whatever i can. I found this the easiest method to follow but was wondering would it work if you left out this and the second if statement?

Comment: also i have to list the names who got the max if you know how i could find the max that would be brilliant

Comment: Andy465: The boolean first is just so that the comma is not added before the first element in the list.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best option is to create a POJO with two fields (name and score) and create an array of it:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Student(String name, int score) {    
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it was intended, but I like the fact, that the instances will be immutable. And since "we" all like to avoid obivous code like the `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` implementation, one can think about using Googles [AutoValue](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14u_h-lMn7f1rXE1nDiLX0azS3IkgjGl5uxp5jGJ75RE) library to create such classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate through the two arrays together in a single iteration and populate an array of the custom type containing a String and double. (i.e. a Student class)

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public double score;
    public Student(String name, double score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}

List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

for (int x = 0; x < classSize; x++)
{
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Student " + counterName++ + " Name: ");
    nameArray[x] = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Student " + counterScore++ + " Score: ");
    scoreArray[x] = input.nextInt();

    sum = sum + scoreArray[x];
    average = sum / classSize;

    // populate array of student
    students.add(new Student(nameArray[x], scoreArray[x]));
}
```

Note that in this case, you don't need to have the `scoreArray` and `nameArray` anymore for better memory utilization.